# Nginx + php-fpm + zend3 - No input file specified

Tags: php, nginx

I'm using vagrant homestead machine as local development environment and I'm having trouble configuring a new zend 3 project.
Actually I have other projects on the same machine and they're working ok.
This one is giving me a "No input file specified" no matter what I put in the configuration file.

I'm running nginx 1.15.8, php7.3 in vagrant homestead 7.
I tried many solutions provided in this site but none was useful.

This is my vhost file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name simulador-preferencias.test;
    root /home/vagrant/code/simulador-preferencias/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/simulador-preferencias.test.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/simulador-preferencias.test-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me get this configuration right?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem.
After you add the vhost to the vagrant machine and edit the Homestead.yml file to add the new site you have to run the following command to generate de correct configuration:

```
vagrant up --provision
```

Note that you'll have to stop the machine to be able to edit the Homestead.yml file or else you'll get an error message.

Stop the machine with:

```
vagrant halt
```